# Remove thanks page on FormSubmit

Tags: html, form-submit

I'm attempting to remove the "thanks" page on my FormSubmit code. I have a function that displays a "success" message below my form, but it's not working because of the thanks page and the redirection.
Any advice for this?

```
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@gmail.com" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Nombre"> Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="Nombre" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Nueva consulta web">
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="Apellido" required>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="Email" required>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Mensaje">Mensaje</label>
            <textarea name="Mensaje" id="message" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Escribinos tu mensaje" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
          <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="_template" value="table">
          <input type="hidden" name="_next" value=" ">
        </form>
```

Comment: The action displays the thanks page and redirect?, if so, you must check the backend.

Comment: Check your  backend page where you form value is submitted/ save in database or mail send because after done redirection active so search and remove it

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an alternative URL for "Thank You" page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://yourdomain.co/contact">
```

This will work as redirect route, and teleport you on that contact page without showing thank you message screen.
Then you can just add an **onClick event listener** that will show you "**success**" message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also checking out FormSubmit, and they have a section in their [documentation page](https://formsubmit.co/documentation) that explains how to get rid of it:

> "By default, after submitting a form the user is shown the FormSubmit "Thank You" page. You can provide an alternative URL for "Thank You" page."

```
    <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://yourdomain.co/thanks.html">
```

So, in your form HTML tags, add that line of code and swap out "https://yourdomain.co/thanks.html" with your own URL